# Answer in Low Quality Posts review queue without flag

Tags: support, bug, review, flags, low-quality-posts

I encountered this [Low Quality Posts review queue item](https://chess.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/16026) on Chess Stack Exchange. I was curious who had flagged it, but to my surprise the mod timeline doesn't show a Very Low Quality / Not An Answer flag by either the system or a user. Normally, both pending and handled flags are shown there. Also, the moderator dashboard shows no pending flag and neither does it appear on the moderator's history pages. The 'Show flag history' in the mod menu is disabled as well.

[image]
[image]

How is this possible? It seems to happen more often, [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/397319/121968) is another case on Ask Different. Webmasters user @Steve discovered another case; unlike my cases, this happened on a very old answer: [Why was a 10 year old question/ answer suddenly marked as low quality?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1692/53036)

Comment: Was it automatically put there by the system filter perhaps? Some posts are auto-flagged, I don't know how those would look like here but I imagine there would be no *real* flag raised in those cases.

Comment: @Mast The system filter you're talking about raises Very Low Quality (auto) flags in name of the Community user. That happens from time to time (and this answer would probably qualify for such a flag, from what I've seen before) but the flag simply isn't there, just a review queue item.

Comment: [Hand of God](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116060/282094)?